# ASP.NET core (VS code) how to install Unobtrusive Ajax library

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, unobtrusive-ajax

I am using Visual Code and would like to install Unobtrusive Ajax library. In Visual Studio, Unobtrusive Ajax library can be installed via Nuget. However, I cannot find a way to install Unobtrusive Ajax library in VS code.

Comment: Why not simply open a terminal (in VS code) and run ` dotnet add package Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax --version 3.2.6 ` in your project root?

Comment: Hi B12Toaster, I have installed and found <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax" Version="3.2.6" /> under .csproj file, but cannot find jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js file in any folder. Please help

Comment: Have you solved the problem yet?